# How to render HTML String without using WebView and NSAttributString, Like in Gmail Thread.(iOS+Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am building an iOS app with has a thread like Gmail. Every cell has to display `HTML string` like in Gmail (Contains text and promotional emails) in Swift 4. If I convert `HTML String` to `NSAttributedString`, Promotional emails are distorting and text and images are overlapping. If I use WebView, it is reloading every time cell appears and height won't be dynamic.

Comment: you should use NSAttributedString and fix your layout.

Comment: @rv7284 How do I fix the layout?

Comment: make proper constraints.

Comment: @rv7284 I am using the same, I want to display HTML Content like Promotional Mails (A Responsive WebPage with images, header, footer).